# How do i efficiently send my react built app to other person

Tags: reactjs

i have built a single page web application using react as part of an assignment.
i have created build version of it using serve -s build.

now my entire application takes around 200MB.

how do i share my application to the person who gave me this assignment so that he can check my work and output?

do i have to send him entire application folder(200MB size)?

or is there a way to send few files which will be enough for him to run the app.

please let me know possible ways of sharing my react application with him.

Comment: *Ask him.* We can't know what he expects you to do.

Comment: @jjj okay sure .i will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the application 200MB+ because of the dependencies/node_modules?

You can probably exclude these as they should be in your package.json file, i.e. they can be requested again if required.

Then you can send the source code and your built version to him.

Comment: @harey yes node modules folder takes up 95% size.

Answer (score 1):

i figured out that only build folder(20MB) is enough run my app. 
i copied build folder into another new folder("deploy-app").
now i opened "deploy-app" folder in VS code and ran following command "serve -s build" and it started working without any problems.